# Why the simulated event not working on the links specified?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom-events, mouseevent

The idea of the program: Check the links , and just on hovering over the link ,  open the link if it has class="open" and textContent "Elzero";

The problem is that the code isn't running as expected and it doesn't open the link on hovering over it (The second link in the list is the one targeted).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        for (let i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
            if (document.links[i].classList.contains("open") && 
            document.links[i].textContent === "Elzero") {
                document.links[i].onmouseenter = function () {
                    document.links[i].click();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="open" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a class="open" href="https://elzero.org" target="_blank">Elzero</a>
    <a class="not" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    <a class="linked" href="https://linkedin.com" target="_blank">Elzero</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `<script>` right before the closing body tag so that the anchor elements actually exist at the time it is run.

```html
    <script>
        for (let i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
            if (document.links[i].classList.contains("open") && 
            document.links[i].textContent === "Elzero") {
                document.links[i].onmouseenter = function () {
                    document.links[i].click();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```